# How can I make a better model of one column tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I am writing an application where I have a table to store different kinds of Assets, each asset has a Brand and each brand has N number of Models. Problem is I only need to store the names of the different brands and models and it doesn't seems right to me to have two different tables with just one column each to store this. Is there a better way to model this?

This is what the ER diagram of that part of my app looks like at the moment:

[image: ER Diagram]

Comment: "...I only need to store the names of the different brands and models..." - Well, yes... today. This is a good structure that supports many unpredictable future changes. If you start with this model, then changes in the future will be simple.

Comment: According to your approach, it seems, the data duplication will take place and your table will not be in a normal form. Ideally, you should have the multiple tables with mapping keys.

Comment: Could you point out where the data duplication would happen in the model I posted?

Comment: "I only need to store the names of the different brands and models ".  Your data model explicitly shows an `id` and `name`.  I'm confused.

Comment: Thats just an auto-generated id as primary key

Comment: If you are not talking about millions of "Assets", simply spell out the "brand" and "model" in the `Assets` table.  (There is such a thing as over-normalizing.)